# twitter bootstrap - What does the showopacity class do?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the function of the `showopacity` class in Bootstrap ? I keep seeing it in code like this

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
```

[Source](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/side-menu-on-hover) (HTML tab line 13)

And why isn't there any doc relating to the functionality of that class ?

Comment: may be its a custom class by the designer

Comment: `showopacity` is not defined in bootstrap anywhere, the developer may have created for a purpose, but in the bootsnipp its really doing nothing...

Comment: @SauravRastogi Is there a list of all the bootstrap classes that I can find somewhere ? So that I can verify if a particular class is actually from bootstrap or not ?

Comment: @ng.newbie All bootstrap classes: https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145

Comment: @Arkej Is it updated to the most recent version of bootstrap ?

Comment: @ng.newbie Probably not. But I found updated list: https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-4-css-classes-index/